# Two friends in MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb

I want to store data about people who are friends to each other in MongoDB database.

For example I want to store that `aaa@gmail.com` and `bbb@gmail.com` are friends.

I created schema with field:

```
emailCombo: {type: String, trim: true},
```

Here I store two emails, for example `aaa@gmail.com#bbbgmail.com` ('lower' email comes first so I always know how to connect emails).

In this way it is easy to check if any two given emails are friends.

The problem is when I want to find all friends of a given email.

What is the best approach to such a 'friends' problem in MongoDB?

Comment: This is an... unorthodox approach to storing friendships. Why didn't you create a Friendship model with fields like `user1` and `user2`?

Comment: Why such a unique way of relating two documents. You can simply add a `friends` field in each document with an array that contains usernames of the friends. Have a look at this : http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65612078649/schema-design-for-social-inboxes-in-mongodb

Comment: And what do you mean by **lower** in ('lower' email comes first so I always know how to connect emails).

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera: lexicographic order

Comment: Don't store friends like this.  The second email address is unsargable.

Comment: Don't store friends like this. `#` is a valid character in email address.

Comment: Don't store friends like this.  `aaa@gmail.com#bbb@gmail.com` would need to be equivilent to `bbb@gmail.com#aaa@gmail.com`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev having two fields: user1 and user2 will make it difficult to check if user1 is friend with user2 because I would need to query like: "find all documents where (user1 == 'aaa@gmail.com' and user2=='bbb@gmail.com) or (user2 == 'aaa@gmail.com' and user1==bbb@gmail.com).
Finding all friends of aaa@gmail.com would also be difficult.
Or maybe I get it wrong?

Comment: @JacekWojcik: you could employ the same logic: lexicographically lesser email goes to user1. An alternative is to create reversed records. If user A befriends user B, you create two friendships: (user1=A, user2=B) and (user1=B, user2=A).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev after giving it some extra thought I think that keeping lexicographic order like aaa@gmail.com#bbb@gmail,com is a good idea. It makes checking if two emails are friends easy. It is also easy to find all friends of aaa@gmail.com -> all I have to do is search for documents with phrase with aaa@gmail,com in it. It is unlikely to find emails like a123@gmail,com and 123@gmail.com but nevertheless I will provide some extra logic for documents found to extract friend email and deal with such cases.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Such approach makes checking if two emails are friends as easy as possible. Finding friends of selected email is also easy.

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera this approach keeps database smaller.

Comment: @JacekWojcik: yeah, you see, now you already have to provide additional logic. And maybe some more logic will be needed in the future. Whereas if you stored emails separately, you wouldn't have to add _any_ additional logic. It's dead simple and robust.